# How to calculate $(6+5x+3x^2)\pmod5$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I need to calculate $(6+5x+3x^2)\pmod5$.

I'm not very much familiar with modulo arithmetic but it seems that the result should be:
$$6\pmod5+5x\pmod5+3x^2\pmod5=1+5x\pmod5+3x^2$$
 I'm not sure what happens with $5x$. Does it become $0\cdot x$?

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(6%2B5x%2B3x%5E2)mod5) gives a different result:.

Comment: @TobyMak how does this help me?

Comment: Split the calculations up into different cases such that $x=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: I'm not very versed in this subject but it seems to me that there's a general solution without the need to split into cases. My question is in general what happens with the coefficient of a polynomial over modulo

Comment: What do you mean by "general solution"?

Comment: @TobyMak the one with $x$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60949/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-yos).